# SSRS Grouping, Totals and Page Breaks

Tags: reporting-services, grouping

I'm using SSRS 2008 R2 Client Side Reporting.
I have a sorted dataset with customer branch-number, account-number, name, and account balance.
I have a parent group set up on "branch number".
Each time the branch number changes, I want to print totals and start a new page with the next branch detail rows.

Currently, the report prints group1 customers, then group2, etc. until complete and then prints the totals for each group at the very bottom.  This is ok but not the behavior I seek.

Comment: Hmm, your question is very hard to follow without context or a repro. Please consider adding an [sscce](http://sscce.org) with a small sample dataset, and a few steps to set up the report you're having trouble with. It also helps if you then tell us what you've tried to fix the issue, this may help us understand and help you.

Comment: Thanks for the response Jeroen.  I don't have an easy way to give you an example but it's pretty simple.  I have a branch number in my data fields.  My data is sorted by that branch number.  Every time it changes, I want to print totals and begin printing on a new page.  So far, I have been able to make totals come out right but they all show up at the end of the report and don't stop-break-show during the report.  Hope this helps you and others understand my request.  It HAS to be easy in reporting services.  ??

Comment: Example
BR Name BAL
01 Jon  $125
01 Sue  $100
01 Totals $225
new page
02 Jane $100
02 Jon  $100
02 Total $300
new page

Comment: You can add the extra information to your question by editing it. If substantial, this will boost your question to the front page again as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may arise from not showing the top-level group column. Perhaps you deleted it or moved that label elsewhere. If so, what you'll have to do is go to the Row Group panel, select that group, and note the cell(s) that are highlighted above. Right click on that cell, and make sure that the correct Row Group is still highlighted in your Row Group panel, and select Insert Row > Outside Group. This will create a row that is at end of each grouping. Add your total expressions to cells in this row. `=SUM(Field!AccountBalance.Value)`